# MongoDB Schema Design - enable atomicity

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection based on the following MongoDB schema, this involves eCommerce transactions and I have purposefully used a single document to achieve atomicity for any updates as can be seen below.

I will have the following three use cases in the report.

1. Do a sum of all the customerTransactions in all the states.
2. Do a sum of all the customerTransactions in each state seperately pending/confirmed/available/redeemed.
3. Do a sum of all the customerTransactions in a redeemed state , grouping by the dates.

The use cases 1 & 2 are straight forward to me , however for use case #3 , can I do anything more to the schema to make it more easier to achieve.

```
    {
      "_id":"id",
      "cuid":"CUIDFromCustomerCollection",
      "customerTransactions":{

        {
        "retailer":"www.walmart.com","purchaseAmount":"123.00","cashbackAmount":"12.00","state":"pending","transactionTimestamp":"timestampValue","updateTimestamp":"timestampValue"
        },
        {
          "retailer":"www.walmart.com","purchaseAmount":"123.00","cashbackAmount":"12.00","state":"confirmed","transactionTimestamp":"timestampValue","updateTimestamp":"timestampValue"
        } , 
        {
          "retailer":"www.walmart.com","purchaseAmount":"123.00","cashbackAmount":"12.00","state":"available","transactionTimestamp":"timestampValue","updateTimestamp":"timestampValue"
        } ,
          {
          "retailer":"www.walmart.com","purchaseAmount":"123.00","cashbackAmount":"12.00","state":"redeemed","transactionTimestamp":"timestampValue","updateTimestamp":"timestampValue"
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The design is good for all the three use cases.

Indexing on "customerTransactions.state" will help in optimization.